# RTK Query not adding new item to the list after post request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am fetching data from jsonplaceholder. It works correctly. But I want to add new position to the list using RTK query. Request is being submitted successfully, but the new item is not being added to my list.
What I am doing wrong?

That's my slice:

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const apiUsersSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "apiUsersSlice",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://my-json-server.typicode.com",
  }),
  tagTypes: ['Users'],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getUsers: builder.query({
      query: () => "/karolkproexe/jsonplaceholderdb/data",
      providesTags: ['Users'],
      transformResponse: (response) => {
        const data = response.map((obj) => ({
            id: obj.id,
            name: obj.name,
            username: obj.username,
            city: obj.address.city,
            email: obj.email,
          }));
        return data;
      },
    }),
    addUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: '/karolkproexe/jsonplaceholderdb/data',
        method: 'POST',
        body,
        invalidatesTags: ['Users'],
      }),
      transformResponse: (response) => response.data,
    }),
  }),
});
export const { useGetUsersQuery, useAddUserMutation } = apiUsersSlice;
```

That's my store file:

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit"
import { apiUsersSlice } from "./api/apiUsersSlice";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer : {
        [apiUsersSlice.reducerPath] : apiUsersSlice.reducer,
    },
    middleware : (getDefaultMiddlewares) => 
        getDefaultMiddlewares().concat(apiUsersSlice.middleware),
})
```

And of course the index file:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ApiProvider } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/dist/query/react";
import { apiUsersSlice } from "./api/apiUsersSlice";
import {store} from './store';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

If it's not possible to add new item to the list because of fake json server, what can I do to solve my problem?
I thought about saving data from rtk query to local storage and then to operate on it, but I found some answers that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it's likely the use of `jsonplaceholder` here that's the issue.

The normal RTK Query usage pattern is that you use a "mutation" request to send an update to the server, then have RTK Query automatically re-fetch the "query" data via matching tags.

However, `jsonplaceholder` doesn't support *actually* updating data on the server.  My understanding is that you can send a `POST` or `PUT` request and it will respond `200 OK`, but there's no actual update made - the data is all fixed and does not change.  So, even if RTKQ does try to re-fetch the data, it gets the *same* query response as last time.

You'll need to have a more realistic server that your client app talks to in order to experiment with using mutations and actually updating data.

Comment: The problem is that I must use jsonplaceholder for this task. So, it's possible to fetch this data as I am doing now, save it in localstorage and operate on it with possibility to adding new items?

Answer (score 0):

Your nesting is off:
`invalidatesTags` needs to be part of the mutation, not the `query` function return value.

```js
    addUser: builder.mutation({
      query: (body) => ({
        url: '/karolkproexe/jsonplaceholderdb/data',
        method: 'POST',
        body,
      }),
      invalidatesTags: ['Users'],
      transformResponse: (response) => response.data,
    }),
```

Comment: This doesn't matter. I had to update entries manually.

Comment: Because as the other answer implies, your api does not update data on the server. 
But if you ever use RTK Query with a real api, your above code will be a bug and this is the fix.
So you should look out for this pattern and use the correct pattern in the future.